# Image display using javascript from a servlet response

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I am trying to display a banner ad using this JS code

```
    document.write('<div><span><script type="text/javascript" \n\
src="http://localhost:8080/Adserver/adserver?id=' + pubcode +'><\/script></span></div>');
```

"http://localhost:8080/Adserver/adserver" is a servlet code which brings the image url as response. But I am still unable to render the image.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing a closing quote for the image's `src`:

```
document.write('<div><span><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/Adserver/adserver?id=' + pubcode +'"><\/script></span></div>');
```